# How to move a SVG using jQuery SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have written the following in a JavaScript method :

```
<html>
...
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(function() {

    $('#layout').svg({});

    var svg = $('#layout').svg('get');
    svg.rect(150, 50, 100, 50, 10, 10, {fill: 'grey'});
    svg.text(200, 75, "Some Text", {'font-family':"Verdana", 'font-size':20, 'text-anchor':"middle", 'fill':"#00ff00"});               

    $('#layout').click(function(e) {
        $(this).slideDown("slow");                    
    });
}
...
<body>
    <div id="layout" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Ultimately I am trying to get 'layout' to move across the browser window.  However I cannot get the 'layout' to move in anyway using slideDown() or animate().  How to I accomplish the effect?

----- Update (September 25, 2011) ------

I got it work with the following code.  Thanks to Jason for tipping me off on the problem:

```
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8">

...

    <style type="text/css">
        #layout {
            background: #6699FF;
            height: 480px;
            width: 640px;
            position: relative;
        }
      </style>       

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        $(function() {
            $('#layout').svg({});

            var svg = $('#layout').svg('get');
            svg.rect(150, 50, 100, 50, 10, 10, {fill: 'grey'});

            svg.text(200, 75, "SomeText", {'font-family':"Verdana", 'font-size':20, 'text-anchor':"middle", 'fill':"#00ff00"});

            $('#layout').click(function(e) {
                $("#layout").animate({opacity: "0.1", left: "-=800"}, 500);                
            });
        });        

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="layout"></div>            
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to get a div to move across the entire window, regardless if it contains SVG or not, make sure its `position` is `absolute` in the CSS. You can then animate the `left` and `top` properties with jQuery.